# cPnginx plugin does not allow execution of Perl files

Tags: perl, nginx, cgi

I had someone install cPnginx-10.7 on a cPanel server. As a result, whenever one tried to access any .pl scripts, the script would be downloaded instead of executed. I had to uninstall the plugin.

Is there a way to allow for Perl to be executed while using it?

Comment: So you're trying to execute CGI scripts on nginx? Have you even searched for instructions?

Comment: It is not exactly on nginx; it is nginx over Apache.

Comment: Even cPnginx Support have trouble sorting this out. Looks like cPnginx  and Perl are not happy with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions:
1. In cpnginx admin interface from WHM change the domain to "Proxy" (Nginx proxy server in front of Apache). This slows down things though.
2. WHM > Install a Perl module, install Nginx (thus one can maintain a "hybrid" option for the domain.